# Problem with Enable/disable text box in Gridview, with javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ascx

thanks in advance for your help: I have a Gridview, the TextBox is activated only when the checkbox is activated. I managed to do this function in Javascript. But the problem is that the textbox is enabled by default (see image). It is deactivated after pressing the checkbox twice. I would like to solve this problem could you please help me. Thank you so much !  [Look the image here !!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG4gR.jpg)

Here my code :

```
<div>
       <asp:GridView ID="gvModifOuvrageNonControles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SkinID="MarionGridView">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MirePrincipal" HeaderText="OUVRAGE PRINCIPAL" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LibelleMireSecondaire" HeaderText="OUVRAGE SECONDAIRE" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NON CONTROLE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbInspection" OnClick="grisé(this);" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField> 
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Libellel" HeaderText="LIBELLE DES MS,VI,PI,SU,CP,PL,PF" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RAISON">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCause" On runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function grisé(obj) {
            var rowData = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
            if (rowData.cells[2].firstElementChild.checked == false) {
                rowData.cells[4].firstElementChild.disabled = true;
            }
            else {
                rowData.cells[4].firstElementChild.disabled = false;

            }}

    </script>
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if you are targeting the right elements or checked the browsers console for any errors? Use ````console.log()```` to verify.

Comment: @JohnPete22 Hi, yes i am targeting the right elements. I just want to make the text box disable by default and then it changes with the javascript function.

Comment: Then why not have ````Enabled="False"```` on the textbox? That way it's disabled at first, and then your javascript will enable it on check.

Comment: @JohnPete22 I've already try this but if you see the image you will see that the textbox is enabled in both cases. I want the textbox to be enable only if the checkbox is true.

Comment: On your initial loading of the page, do you have a RowDataBound function for the GridView where you determine whether the checkbox is checked or not?

Comment: Yes!( it's too long so i cut it ) for (int i = 0; i < _lstGpeCompo.Count; i++)
                    {
                        
                        if (_lstGpeCompo[i].Inspection == true)
                        {
                            ((CheckBox)gvModifOuvrageNonControles.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("cbInspection")).Checked = true;
                        }
                        ((TextBox)gvModifOuvrageNonControles.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("txtCause")).Text = _lstGpeCompo[i].CauseNonInspection;
                    }
                }
            }:

Comment: Can you show us the code to bound the grid?

Comment: That's the only code i have

Comment: You may need to add  `FindControl("txtCause").Enabled = false` as first line inside your loop, then
`FindControl("txtCause").Enabled = true` inside your if

Comment: Thank you so much !!! It succeded !

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `Enable` property of the textbox to `false`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCause" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I've already try this but if you see the image you will see that the textbox is enabled in both cases. I want the textbox to be enable only if the checkbox is true

Comment: The above code should disable the textbox by default, then maybe you have another code that makes it enabled.